# iOS - UILabel loading, but no text displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have implemented my own `UITableViewCell` and created a `.xib` for it. I have connected all the labels using a strong `IBOutlet` and initialized the `UILabels` in the `awakeFromNib()` method. However, whenever I run the iOS Simulator, I run into an issue where the `UILabel` is `(null)` in `NSLog`.

I am wondering if it has to do with how I am loading in the text for the UILabel. I have tried to create a shortened version of the project below that outlines the issue I'm running into.

I would also like to note that I can click on the actual rows, but that there is still no text displaying.

My code:

**ToDoCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ToDoCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *minutesLeft;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *hoursLeft;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *daysLeft;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *taskLabel;

@end
```

**ToDoCell.m**

```
#import "ToDoCell.h"

@implementation ToDoCell

@end
```

**ToDoViewController.m**

```
#import "ToDoViewController.h"
#import "ToDoCell.h"

@interface ToDoViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;

@end

@implementation ToDoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self loadInitialData];
}

- (void)loadInitialData {
    NSString *item1 = @"Testing";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item1];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ToDoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ToDoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.taskLabel.text = @"Testing";
    NSLog(@"Fudge Monkeys: %@", cell.taskLabel.text);

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you connect taskLabel with nib. Or add taskLabel to cell? If you use cell nib, remove init.  If not (using code), add it to cell after init.

Comment: why you are intilizing them

Comment: Just create an iBOutlet and use it

Comment: just don't init the labels! (that will overwrite your xib, you only do that when you're not using xibs)

Comment: I commented out the initializations, and now all of the UILabels are null.

Comment: @Zhouster have you connect into nib all labels.

Comment: @NimitParekh Yes. I connected all of them into the nib via Ctrl + drag to interface.

Comment: have you registered the cell? also confirm in .xib by right click on the control to see if they are actually conected.

Comment: @Usama83 Yeah, I have connected them, but I'm still getting null for the labels when I try to access it.

Comment: @Zhouster if you setup a git repo for your scenario, it would be alot helpful.

Comment: have you implemented the numberOfRowsInSection method? You must tell you Table view, how many rows it should create

Comment: @Zhouster Here I attached sample code for your problem may that help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Issue** is you are creating new objects for labels but then you are not adding them to superview but calling `[self addSubview:label]` ssigning them to properties does not add them to super view.

**But** this is totally unnecessary you should not init them in `awakeNib`. , and one thing more I will say about your code now you don't need to use @`synthesis` anymore as well. Any particular reason you are making IBOutlets strong?

**Update** you need to register nib with `tableView` first add following lines in `viewDidLoad`

```
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ToDoCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ToDoCell"];
```

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:)

Comment: By "use them," do you mean to just directly reference the UILabel variables?

Comment: use them means referring them when need as you are doing  cell.taskLabel li.text

Comment: Just FYI, didn't mean to copy your answer. There is just 6 seconds difference.

Comment: This did the trick! Though, could I ask you to break down what exactly it's doing?

Comment: When you are defining a cell in a nib, then before decqueue you have to register that nib with tableView, and on dequeue if its first time it will create an object automatically, other wise you have to create cell and your self.

Comment: It is telling your tableview that it supposed to load its cells from a nib file and the cell identifier will be "ToDoCell".

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If the `UILabel` instances are connected in Interface Builder via `IBOutlet`, you must not initialize them explicitly.

Just delete the complete `awakeFromNib()` method

Comment: Even after deleting the method, when I log the label, it says it's null. Why may that be?

Comment: is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` called at all? Where do you reload the table data?

Comment: Yes, it is called. It's called during an unwind segue (that I left out of the displayed code). Also, the log files show up with a `(null)` for the labels.

Answer (score 1):

First of all delete `awakeFromNib` and make sure that you gave `Cell Identifier` in cell nib file.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ToDoCell";
     ToDoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

     if (!cell)
         cell = [[ToDoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];
     cell.taskLabel.text = @"Testing";
     return cell;
 }
```

Don't forget to add following code for register nib.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ToDoCellTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ToDoCell"];
}
```

[Here is the sample code for your problem.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nimitparekh/files/Interactive%20Pushnotification%20IOS8/UItableViewDemo.zip/download)

May this help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in `viewDidLoad`

```
NSString *strName = NSStringFromClass([ToDoCell class]);
[self.toDoItems registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:strName bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:strName];
```

You are using xib file but not loading it by registering it for the tableView. This is required when you use separate xib file. If you do not register, then only class will load and xib won't. And your `awakeFromNib` won't be called.

Answer (score 0):

You .xib why cell should be set through:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ToDoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[ToDoCell reuseIdentifier]];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = (ToDoCell *)
               [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ToDoCell" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
    }

    cell.taskLabel.text = @"Testing";
    NSLog(@"Fudge Monkeys: %@", cell.taskLabel.text);

    return cell;
}
```